# Why is my emmc card recognized as /dev/sdd instead of /dev/mmcblk0?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, sd-card

My desktop has a built-in SD/mini/MMC/RS card slot and I can use my eMMC card as storage device without problems. But under `/dev` directory it is recognized as `/dev/sdd`, which I think should be `/dev/mmcblk0` or something. Here's the output of `dmesg -T` concerning `sd` part:

```
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:2: [sdd] 15269888 512-byte logical blocks: (7.81 GB/7.28 GiB)
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:2: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:2: [sdd] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:2: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:2: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015]  sdd: sdd1
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:3: [sde] Attached SCSI removable disk
[Thu Nov  5 10:57:14 2015] sd 5:0:0:2: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The problem is that I want to use `ioctl` with `MMC_IOC_CMD` request to test its functionality, so I can compare the result/response with another FPGA-simulated eMMC controller. On an embedded arm board with Linux (3.0.1) installed this same eMMC card is recognized correctly as `/dev/mmcblk0`, and I can successfully send some commands to it. But on the Desktop, `open("/dev/sdd", O_RDWR)`, then `ioctl(fd, IOC_MMC_CMD, args)` returns `EINVAL`.

Maybe the problem is the card isn't correctly recognized as sd/mmc card? How could I make it realized as `mmcblkX` so that I can interact with it on my PC (Arch Linux)?

Comment: If you look closer, you'll probably notice that the reader is a usb device internally or something like that and not a directly accessible SD card reader.

Comment: @Harvey `lsusb` does list it as USB device. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: On modern computers often you have an advertised SSD which is actually eMMC. I think it might be related to this. Didn't check Linux kernel for this, though.

Comment: How is this related to embedded devices? (rethorical question - it is not)